# How can I set an icon and update the title of my tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am attempting to produce a small program to better understand how tkinter works within python.

As such I wanted to know how I can set an icon and update the title of a tkinter window.

I have written the below code, is anyone able to advise on how I would achieve the above within this script?

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as Tk
import ttk

class Test(Tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

app = Test()
app.state("zoomed")
app.mainloop()
# I'm having problems with this could I get any help?
app.wm_iconbitmap('xxxxxxx.ico')
app.title('Vikings Lore')
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Have you asked this to Google? Any basic tutorial should cover this.

Comment: Say no more! [tour], [ask], [MCVE]

Comment: No, You actualy have no question a title is not enought! And 2 picture of code or a car is pretty mutch the same. Use the [edit] button to make the question readable!

Comment: Pretend you're talking to a colleague. Would you ask something to a collegue staring at him in the eyes while showing him a picture of your code?

Comment: Ok, now you have send him a piece of code by email would you like to make a descriptive sentece that will help him understand what you are asking. Because It's a busy collegue and you know with out least 155 char of description your mail will be ignore.

Comment: Is it hard to understand my code?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking, what you've done is post code and said "Give me the answer", not only is that rude and presumptuous it's also not what Stack Overflow is for.
We are here to help you through programming problems in order to create a library that others can view and learn from, this does not contribute to that in any regard.

Comment: should I put app.title('xxx')?

Comment: **"Is it hard to understand my code?"**, Call me Dumb-dumb then tell how long you would have take to type : _"I want to replace the Tkinter icon by my own `path_Exemple` and rename the XYZ. I have try XY, I have search XY "_? Step one make sentence, Explain what you what, what you have try. and why it didn't work.

Comment: Please can you phrase this as a question, as stated previously, the point of stack overflow is to create a library for other developers to learn from.
If they have to trawl through the comments it won't help anyone.

Comment: I have added a suggested edit to your question, please review and learn that we're people in a community working together.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the title of a tkinter window using the below snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.wm_title("Hello, world")
```

This will set the title of the root window to `Hello, world`.
As for the icon, this can be set using the below snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
```

This will set the icon of the root window to the file `icon.ico`.

If you need further basic help with tkinter http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ is your best friend.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux (worked for me) you need add also '@' at the begin of string:

```
app_icon = '/home/user/icons/number-three_66512.XBM'
root.iconbitmap('@' + app_icon)
```

If you get error `_tkinter.TclError: error reading bitmap file`  use XBM format instead of ICO.